# weak convergence in an unit ball.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

let $x_n \rightarrow x$ weakly and $x_n \in \overline{B(0,1)}$ for all $n$ and $\|x\|_H = 1$ then $\|x_n-x\|_H \rightarrow 0$. We can write $\|x_n -x \|_H^2 = <x,x>+<x_n,x_n> -2Re<x_n,x> = 0$ when i apply the weak convergence assumption. Not sure if my argument is correct since, i did not use that assumption that $x_n \in \overline{B(0,1)}$ for all $n$ and $\|x\|_H = 1$.

Comment: Weak convergence alone doesn't allow you to conclude that $\langle x_n,x_n\rangle\to\langle x,x\rangle$.

Comment: sure we can use the fact that $x_n \in \overline{B(0,1)}$ and we obtain an estimate $<x_n,x_n> \leq 1$

Comment: and $<x,x> = 1$ then weak convergence for the $Re<x_n,x>$ and we are done

Comment: @P.P.Tuong oh i see it now why we need these assumptions, thanks